Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword does not create additional data fields in collection
In my IOS signup page, I am using the following code:
firebaseConfig.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
            .then(id => {
              if (id) {
                const data = {
                  id: id.user.uid,
                  planid: 'APPLE',
                  plancreated: new Date(),
                  email: id.user.email,
                }

               firebaseConfig
                  .firestore()
                  .collection('user')
                  .doc(id.user.uid)
                  .set(data).then(() => {
                    alert("Done!")
                  }).catch(err => {
                    alert(err.message)
                  })
            }}).catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
              setErrorMsg(err.message)
              setTogle(false)
            });

Firebase creates the user but does not create the additional data in the 'user' collection. I have persistence enabled - but just wondering why it would not create the additional data.

What do you mean by "does not create the additional data"? What exactly is written and what not?

It only creates the user in authentication - nothing in the user collection

When you're using createUserWithEmailAndPassword() and then calling then() you actually create the user in Firebase Authentication and if the operation fails you catch the error. However, when you try to write the data to Firestore, you're blindly assuming that the operation succeeds, which is not correct because a write operation in Firestore can fail due to many reasons. So to solve this, try calling again then() and catch the error message.
In my opinion, the write operation fails due to improper security rules. Most likely you'll get a message that sounds like this:

PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions

To solve this, please read the answer from the below post:

firestore: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions


Hi Alex, I dont get any permission denied errors. Can you explain when I should call then again? Is it after the if(id) loop?

You'll get that error message right after you call then().
So you should call it after .set(data). Give it a try and tell me if it works.

No luck unfortunately

"No luck unfortunately" doesn't provide enough information so I can help. What exactly doesn't work? Does this answer help?

It still doesn’t show any error and does not add anything to the user collection with the id

Please edit your question and add the changed code, so I can take a look at it.

Changed question - the alert of Done or the alert of the error are never triggered

I should note, that this only seems to effect IOS/Safari - Android/Chrome it works just fine
